# Automation testing tool/Framework for Ionic/Cordova/Hybrid App

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, ionic2, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an Ionic Hybrid application for Android /iOS. I want to test the app using selenium kind of framework.

currently i am using Appium which has not have more option to find/target the elements in an Ionic app (angular 2 app) .

so please let me know the suitable tool or framework.

If i am asking the question in the wrong forum,please suggest me the suitable medium to raise my question

Answer (score 1):

You should try Karma and Jasmine for Unit Testing, this two articles can help you:

- [How To Write Automated Tests For Your Ionic App - Part 1](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-your-ionic-app-part-1/)
- [How to Unit Test an Ionic 2 Application](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-unit-test-an-ionic-2-application/)

The first tutorial is about Ionic 1 which uses Angular 1, but I think you can suit it up for your code.It also talks about how to test the end-to-end and the UI, with Protactor so I hope it will be useful.

The second one is about how to implement the same testing frameworks for Ionic 2 app.

I don't know Selenium that much, but I really liked how these frameworks can give you a solution for Ionic.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a year since asking this question so I'm sure you have formed some kind of end-to-end solution.

I've added id='mybutton' and [id]="'item'+item.id" attributes to my static and dynamic html markup elements respectively. Compilers are terrible at reliably naming elements while transpiling code so it is better to bake testability in up front.

With that you should be able to automate testing a majority of the functionality within a simple web browser within your build chain.

Testing non-browser supported - device dependent - features like using the camera or contacts will require either a polyfill or mock to complete the headless test automation. Another option is to launch your tests within an emulator but that requires a different set of tools to be proficient.